# Unable to access IP number of Web Site created in IIS-10

Tags: iis-10

I have created a web site in IIS-10 Windows Server2016. My server has a public valid IP.

[image]

I have no problem loading that web site in same server.

But I can't reach that web site from a client browser.

http://173.2xx.14.1xx:82/

[image]

What is missing?

I also have modified hots file, but no success.
[image]

Comment: It's a firewall problem.

Comment: Firewall in server or in client?

Comment: The server and the network the server is connected to.

Comment: Thank you. I set up rule in Server Firewall to allow port 82.

Comment: Incidentally - the IP addresses in the images are very easy to work out despite the black marks on them.